# Encoding for getting contents of a url IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, url

I want to get the contents of a url hosted by me. The contents of the url is

```
<p class="citation_style_APA">Blaine, J. D. (1992). <i>Buprenorphine: An alternative treatment for opioid dependence</i>. Rockville, MD: U.S. Dept. of Health and Human Services, Public Health Service, Alcohol, Drug Abuse, and Mental Health Administration, National Institute on Drug Abuse. </p>
```

Below is my code to get the above contents in a string.

```
NSString *s =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@"xyz.com"];
url = [NSURL URLWithString:s];
NSString *content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:nil];
NSLog(@"%@",content);
```

I am getting null, can anyone tell where i am going wrong.

Comment: You need a valid URL such as `http: //xyz.com`.

Comment: And get rid of the `stringWithFormat:`. Just do `NSString *s = @"http://whatever.com";`.

Comment: It is a valid url hosted in my server, i just put dummy here!!

Comment: Then use the `error` parameter so you can see what the problem is.

Comment: you missed the scheme of URL "http".

Answer (score 0):

Try a complete web address, like @"http://www.xyz.com/myfile.html".  Once you get it working, you'll want to change to an asynch technique.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do two things.

```
1. you should use a valid url

2. NSString *content=[[NSString string] initWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:Nil];
```

Now check your Log; It'll definitely work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
NSString *strUrl  = < YOUR URL >
NSURL    *url     = [NSURL URLWithString:[strUrl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSError  *error   = nil;
NSString *content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:&error];
if(content==nil)
    NSLog(@"%@",error!=nil ? error.description : @"");
else
    NSLog(@"%@",content);
```

Comment: Your if statement is wrong. Check if `content` is nil. If it is then check check `error`.